# Locally compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, geometry, geometric-topology

I have to show that

(1) Show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally compact.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzEAX.png

I have provided a link with my answer since it's long and would take me forever to write in here.
Is this proof good enough or do I also need to show that $\mathbb{R}^n$$^-$$^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

And as a side question: is there a shorter/easier proof of this?

(2) Assume that X and Y are locally compact Hausdorff spaces. Show that  X×Y is locally compact.

Since I proved in (1) that  X×Y is locally compact if X and Y are locally compact, do I just refer to that here?

Thank you for your help!
Also: I have provided our definition of being locally compact in my link to (1).

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, by Heine-Borel a set is compact iff it is closed and bounded.
So any open ball $B(x,\varepsilon)  =\{y: d(x,y) < \varepsilon\}$ neighbourhood of $x$ contains a compact neighbourhood of $x$, namely the closed ball $D(x,\delta) = \{y: d(x,y) \le \delta\}$ for $\delta < \varepsilon$ (bounded by definition, closed by a theorem).

(2) is a consequence of the fact that a product of two compact neighbourhoods is a compact neighbourhood in the product.

Comment: Oh, so to (1) can you just argue that since any open ball $B(x,ε)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a compact closure $\bar{B}$$(x,ε)$$={{y\in\mathbb{R}^n:d(x,y)<ε}}$ then $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally compact?

Comment: @Nikolaj yes, that’s valid too. It depends on your definition of local compactness.

Comment: Our definition is that X is called locally compact if there for any p in X exists a neighbourhood U of p such that the closure $\bar{U}$ is compact and  a subset of X

Comment: @Nikolaj in some definitions you have to show there is a local base of compact neighbourhoods.

Comment: so $\mathbb{R}^n$ being locally compact relies heavily on Heine-Borel? @statman